# deactivate active region after `eval-region`

Tags: commands, region, interactive, mark, eval

I do the following to activate the region and evaluate it

```
M-x spc  to begin mark
C-n 
C-n
C-n
M-x eval-region
```

The region is still active (highlighted) after the `eval-region` is performed.

I would prefer if `eval-region` evaluated the region and then deactivated the region, leaving the cursor after the code that was just evaluated.

I have this to start:

```
(defun e-eval-region (START END)
  "Execute region from START to END using `eval-region and unhighlight result."
  (interactive)
  (eval-region START END)
  (keyboard-quit))
```

How do I properly pass `START` and `END` of region to `interactive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (drop the optional arguments, if you want):

```el
(defun e-eval-region (start end &optional printflag read-function)
  (interactive "r")
  (eval-region start end printflag read-function)
  (deactivate-mark))
```

1. Use `C-h f interactive` to see how to pass the region as two interactive arguments.  For more information, see the Elisp manual, node [Using Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).  You can find that node in Emacs using `C-h i`, choosing the Elisp manual, and using `i interactive RET`.
2. The command loop automatically deactivates the region after each command, unless the command takes special measures to prevent that - as does `eval-region`.  You need only deactivate the mark explicitly to counteract that.

Comment: This is great, thank you Drew! I kept the optional arguments for completeness.